# iPhone - adding a UISegmentedControl to a Navigation Controller Toolbar

Tags: iphone

Is this an heresy to add a UISegmentedControl to a navigation Controller Toolbar?

I am considering this code:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"One", @"")],
[NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Two", @"")],
[NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Three", @"")],
[NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Four", @"")],
nil]];

segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];


[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSegment:) 
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[segmentedControl setFrame:[self.navigationController.toolbar bounds]];

[self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];
```

I have tried this code and the segments don't appear to be selected with I touch them.

Is this the correct way of doing that?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to your tintColor being black.  Change the color and you should see the selected segment reflected.

Comment: duuuuhhh! obviously! thanks. But is this ok to add a segmentedControl to a navigation Controller toolbar?

Comment: I think it's fine.  Tons of apps customize the navbars/toolbars.  You are most definitely not alone in that respect.

Comment: well the top 25 on the app store has a segmentedControl. so unless apple breaks their own rules it should be fine :P