# Custom UIBarButtonItem on Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, custom-controls

I want a  two Custom`UIBarButtonItem`on Navigation bar ..this `UiBarButtonItem` should be actually combination of two `UIBarButtonItem`on Navigation bar.. and these button should be combine to each other similar like the `UISegmentControl` ..if can not `UISegmentControl` because i needed for the previous and next button.

So is it possible to combine or customize  two button similar like the `UISegmentControl`.

[image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pjgv.png)

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445682/iphone-adding-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-a-navigation-controller-toolbar . Here in question you can find same what you have asked. Hope it helps you..

Comment: no man I dont want the UISegmentedControl as when you click once on one button ,...you cannnot click again on the same.. I needed for PREVIOUS And NEXT function...so is it possible to combine by customization

Comment: But image you provided is similar to segment control??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0);
fieldAccessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
fieldAccessoryView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
fieldAccessoryView.tag = 200;

[fieldAccessoryView setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

UIBarButtonItem *spaceButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone  target:self action:@selector(done:)];

UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Previous", @""), NSLocalizedString(@"Next", @""), nil]];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[segmentedControl setMomentary:YES];
UIBarButtonItem *segmentButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];

[fieldAccessoryView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:segmentButton, spaceButton, doneButton, nil] animated:NO];
[segmentButton release];
[spaceButton release];
[doneButton release];
[segmentedControl release];
```

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *twoButtons = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:fieldAccessoryView];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = twoButtons;

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[NSString stringWithString:@"First"],
[NSString stringWithString:@"Second"],
nil]];


// Just customize this

[segmentControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE1.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segmentControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE2.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];


[segmentedControl setFrame:[self.navigationController.toolbar bounds]];

[self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];
```

It is rough idea from me.

Comment: no man I dont want the UISegmentedControl as when you click once on one button ,...you cannnot click again on the same.. I needed for PREVIOUS And NEXT function...so is it possible to combine by customization

Answer (score 0):

Following code describe how can add `UIBarButtonItem` in `UINavigationBar`.

**In your case add** `UIBarButtonItem` with `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` that look like `UISegmentControl.`

```
UIToolbar *Toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [Toolbar sizeToFit];

     NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Cancel)];
    [barItems addObject:btnCancel];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(done)];
    [barItems addObject:btnDone];

    [Toolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *twoButtons = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Toolbar];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = twoButtons;
```

// Method of UIBarButtonItem

```
-(void)Cancel
{
  // Write Code for Cancel Method
}

-(void)done
{
  // Write Code for Done Method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code i get this code from some answer before some time and i edit it and use it in my application... try this..

```
NSArray *segItemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segItemsArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;// set your default selected button(view)

UIBarButtonItem *segmentedControlButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:(UIView *)segmentedControl];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

NSArray *barArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: flexibleSpace, segmentedControlButtonItem, flexibleSpace, nil];

[self setToolbarItems:barArray];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

i hope this helpful to you....

Comment: and how to give actions to the `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: here seagement controls delegate method works as a barbutton action event.. just see what i do .. i set segment control so when it clicked segment control delegate method call..

Comment: thats fine but how can to give the actions to the @"One", @"Two", @"Three" button

Comment: refer this tutorial and for segment control you get indexchanged event of segment control see this tutorial http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this help you..**

```
UISegmentedControl *tabNavigation = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Previous", @"Next", nil]];
tabNavigation.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[tabNavigation setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[tabNavigation setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:1];
tabNavigation.momentary = YES;
[tabNavigation addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
UIBarButtonItem *barSegment = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tabNavigation];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

 keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init ];//WithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 44)];

 keyboardDoneButtonView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
 keyboardDoneButtonView.translucent = YES;
 [keyboardDoneButtonView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 44)];
 [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];
 [keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:barSegment,flexSpace,doneButton, nil]];
```

**Example text :**

```
 self.txtGivenName.inputAccessoryView=keyboardDoneButtonView;
 self.txtLastName.inputAccessoryView=keyboardDoneButtonView;



- (void)segmentedControlHandler:(id)sender
 {
if (sender){
    switch ([(UISegmentedControl *)sender selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:
        {
            [self previousClicked]; 
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            [self nextClicked];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

```
  -(void)previousClicked{
UIResponder* nextResponder = [sclView viewWithTag:selected-1];
if (nextResponder)
    {
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

}

```
  -(void)nextClicked{
UIResponder* nextResponder = [sclView viewWithTag:selected+1];
if (nextResponder)
    {
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

}

Comment: whats the `txtGivenName ` in this ?? for self.txtGivenName.inputAccessoryView=keyboardDoneButtonView;

Comment: set while first responder, will not take effect until reloadInputViews is called.

Comment: leave it first u are requirement is satisfy or not ?

Comment: no actually ...its showing me error ...as keyboardDoneButtonView and txtGivenName is undefined...thts what i am asking from you

Comment: ok i delete that image plz makesure ... if u need like then ping me ....... i will explain :)